# print(foo['bar']) correctly returning value of 'bar', but on next line foo['bar'] is giving a KeyError

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a mongoDB collection populated with episodes of a tv show and I am trying to query this collection to return all episodes in a given season here is my code:

```
@app.route('/api/season', methods=['GET'])
def get_by_season():
season = None

if request.args.get('season'):
    season = request.args.get('season')
    print(season)

data_to_return = []
for episode in episodes.find():
    print(episode['season'])
    if episode['season'] == season:
        print('here')
        episode['_id'] = str(episode['_id'])
        data_to_return.append(episode)

print(data_to_return)

return make_response(jsonify(data_to_return), 200)
```

the line `print(episode['season'])` is correctly giving me the season of each episode i.e 1

but the next line `episode['season'] == 1` gives me a KeyError `KeyError: 'season'` essentially telling me that the key doesn't exist on my episode documents and the line `print('here')` never appears in the terminal so I know the error is in my if statement. But how can this be possible when I've just read and printed the value of each season key?

Thanks for any help and as a reminder I'd like to return all the episodes in a given season. Thanks!

EDIT full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, 
in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", 
line 165, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, 
in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, 
in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", 
line 165, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, 
in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, 
in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, 
in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/matthewdoherty/Documents/Final Year/Full 
Stack/App/app.py", line 128, in get_by_season
print(episode['season'])
KeyError: 'season'
```

Comment: Not familiar with mongodb, so don't have the ability to test, but can you try doing `db_season = episode['season']` then `print(db_season)` followed by `if db_season == season`.  Suspect this is because `find` [returns a cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find), which I think only allows you to access the value once.

Comment: `Print(episode)` and see if it has a 'season' key

Comment: Actually.. you never define `episodes` at all in this code...

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Also fix your indentation on your code sample.

Comment: @JeffUK episodes is defined earlier in the code, print(episode) produces every document in the collection. Here is an example you can see 'season' is included: `{'_id': ObjectId('5fb25842da5ac0ecb1a79858'), 'name': 'The Clearing', 'season': 2, 'number': 7, 'airdate': '2012-11-11', 'runtime': 60,  'summary': '<p>In the aftermath of the ambush, Carrie and the team scramble to gain control of the operation, while Brody attends a well-heeled fund-raiser at a Virginia horse farm. </p>', 'reviews': []}`

Comment: @v25 print(db_season) correctly prints the season of each episode. `if db_season == season` still gives the keyError

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fix your error but it looks like you're making a real meal of your function.

If you just want to return a list of episodes that match on `season`, your function distils down to:

```
def get_by_season():
    return [x for x in episodes.find({'season': season}, {'_id': 0})]
```